# Dataframe Column to list conserving order in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a Spark dataframe containing 2 columns, "id" and "timetamp".
How can i convert the "id" column to a list conserving the original order by timestamp?
When i try collect, the order is not conserved.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating Pandas dataframe, ordering it by timestamp and make a list of id column?

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `collect_list`, since it is nondeterministic collecting of elements over a group, see doc -

```
/**
   * Aggregate function: returns a list of objects with duplicates.
   *
   * @note The function is non-deterministic because the order of collected results depends
   * on order of rows which may be non-deterministic after a shuffle.
   *
   * @group agg_funcs
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def collect_list(e: Column): Column = withAggregateFunction { CollectList(e.expr) }
```

In distributed computing, collecting the elements over certain order is kind of impossible since the data is disributed across nodes. To achieve that you need collect the data to single partition on an executor and then perform aggregation. `This may cause Resource crunch on the executor`. If you know that your data is **less** in number you can do this using `UDAF` by coalescing the data to `1`.

> **If you have repartitioning column which is not skewed then you can perform this action in performant and reliable way**

Here is a good [example](https://github.com/sryza/aas/blob/master/ch08-geotime/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/datascience/geotime/RunGeoTime.scala) to sort values based on timestamp by cloudera